# Declare Varchar - Teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

im trying to save query result to declared varchar but i got error msg "in subquery can't be top n"

```
DECLARE d TIMESTAMP(6);
    SET d  = (SELECT TOP 1 DATE_S FROM db1_SC.LOG_SP_STATUS WHERE SP_ID = 1 AND Status IS NULL AND Date_S IS NOT NULL AND DATE_E IS NULL ORDER BY ID DESC);
```

Comment: It's obviously saying that this syntax is not supported by Teradata. Probably you can do the same thing with `SELECT TOP 1 DATE_S INTO d FROM db1_SC.LOG_SP_STATUS WHERE SP_ID = 1 AND Status IS NULL AND Date_S IS NOT NULL AND DATE_E IS NULL ORDER BY ID DESC`

Comment: but i didn't want to create not nessesary tmp table.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a stored proc? You can only declare variables in stored procedures (and I think macros) in Teradata.  What are you actually trying to do? There is no legitimate reason I can think of to avoid volatile tables, but if you really don't want one, use a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
DECLARE d TIMESTAMP(6);

SELECT t1.DATE_S INTO d 
FROM
    (SELECT DATE_S,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) rn
    FROM db1_SC.LOG_SP_STATUS 
    WHERE SP_ID = 1 AND Status IS NULL AND Date_S IS NOT NULL AND DATE_E IS NULL) t1
WHERE t1.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a TD system to test, but you could try

```sql
DECLARE d TIMESTAMP(6);

SELECT TOP 1 DATE_S INTO d
FROM db1_SC.LOG_SP_STATUS 
WHERE SP_ID = 1 
AND Status IS NULL 
AND Date_S IS NOT NULL 
AND DATE_E IS NULL 
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```